# Neo4j - query performance degradation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Here is my query:

```
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[r:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)-[s:AUTHORED]-(a:Author) 
MATCH (l:Language)-[t:USED]->(w:Woka) 
WHERE (a.author_name =~ '.*Camus.*' and a.author_name =~ '.*Albert.*') 
RETURN p.publisher_name, w.woka_title, a.author_name, l.language_name;
```

The first time this is executing the result is returned in 3.8 seconds. For the second execution couple minutes later the result is returned in 15.1 seconds. The more I am executing the longer the response time. For the third execution the response time is increasing and several moments later I am getting the results between 30 and 90 seconds.

I am the only user of this (development) database. No data is added or deleted or changed there. No indexes are dropped or created also there.
When closing two out of three connections to the database the response time goes back to 15 seconds.

Memory is set 4GB as init and max up to 8GB. Server has 16GB total memory.

What is happening here? Why the response time differs so much?

Comment: How do you execute your queries?

Comment: using the neo4j-shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I borrowed from other solutions and I changed the params as following in the file conf/neo4j.properties (server restarted after that):

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=512M
```

The results are now returning, in average, 300% faster narrowing the time from 90 seconds to 30 seconds and I am not getting disconnected anymore from the web interface to the database.

Answer (score 2):

How big is your graph? Could be that it allocates a lot of heap for caching and then there is not enough space for running the queries without garbage collection.

I presume your relationships are all 1:n, if not add a `WITH distinct p,w,a` in between the two matches.

Your query is also suboptimal, and will probably create a lot of intermediate results, you can use `PROFILE` to look at the query plan.

Try this:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (a:Author)
WHERE (a.author_name =~ '.*Camus.*' and a.author_name =~ '.*Albert.*') 
MATCH (p:Publisher)-[:PUBLISHED]->(w:Woka)<-[:AUTHORED]-(a)
MATCH (l:Language)-[:USED]->(w:Woka) 
RETURN p.publisher_name, w.woka_title, a.author_name, l.language_name;
```

Comment: Trying your suggested query and here are the results. Same number of rows returned: 247 rows
Same response time around 15-16 seconds: 16838 ms
Compiler CYPHER 2.2
Total database accesses: 20687997
Planner COST

Projection
  |
  +Filter(0)
    |
    +Expand(All)(0)
      |
      +Filter(1)
        |
        +Expand(All)(1)
          |
          +Filter(2)
            |
            +Expand(All)(2)
              |
              +Filter(3)
                |
                +NodeByLabelScan

Comment: More details, here are the indexes:
Indexes
  ON :Author(author_id)         ONLINE  
  ON :Author(author_name)       ONLINE  
  ON :Language(language_id)     ONLINE  
  ON :Language(language_name)   ONLINE  
  ON :Publisher(publisher_id)   ONLINE  
  ON :Publisher(publisher_name) ONLINE  
  ON :Woka(woka_id)             ONLINE  
  ON :Woka(author_id)           ONLINE  
  ON :Woka(publisher_id)        ONLINE  
  ON :Woka(language_id)         ONLINE  
  ON :Woka(woka_title)          ONLINE  

No constraints

Comment: neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n:Author) return count(n);
+----------+
| count(n) |
+----------+
| 4136805  |
+----------+
1 row
3643 ms

Comment: neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n:Publisher) return count(n);
+----------+
| count(n) |
+----------+
| 202255   |
+----------+
1 row
358 ms

Comment: neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n:Language) return count(n); 
+----------+
| count(n) |
+----------+
| 274      |
+----------+
1 row
42 ms

Comment: neo4j-sh (?)$ MATCH (n:Woka) return count(n);    
+----------+
| count(n) |
+----------+
| 19798863 |
+----------+
1 row
28535 ms

Comment: Number of nodes: 24.1M, Number of Properties: 50.2M, Number of Relationships: 55.4M, Number of relationships type: 3, Number of node types: 4, Database disk usage: 30.9GB. Hope this helps.

Comment: And sometimes out of the blue I am getting this: Disconnected from Neo4j. Please check if the cord is unplugged.

Comment: In the browser sessions I am getting: Unrecognized transaction id. Transaction may have timed out and been rolled back.
 Neo.ClientError.Transaction.UnknownId
However the neo4j-shell sessions are still connected.